# Powering 12V device from USB-PD port not supporting 12V

Tags: dc-dc-converter, usb-pd

I would like to power a 12V 2.5A device using barrel connector from a 60W USB-PD capable thunderbolt 3 port. I have a few of those pd trigger cables (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000025832414.html) that seemed perfect for the job. However, from my testing the PD port supports 20/15/9/5V but not 12V.

Is there a way to get 12V from usb-pd port that does not support it? Or how can I convert 20V or 15V from the pd trigger to 12V?

I would ideally like to avoid soldering or exposed circuits since we are talking expensive equipment and I would probably do bad job soldering. So I preffer something plug 'n' play if its available and so far I haven't found anything like that.

PS. What I'm trying to do is power HTC Vive Cosmos from Akitio Node Pro eGPU dock to get rid of one AC power supply to make setting up easier when transporting.

Comment: You could certainly use a voltage regulator to convert to 12v. Alternatively, since 12v is very close to 15v, and internal voltage regulators are very common in DC devices, you could look at the internals of the device and see if it actually needs 12v or if it is regulating everything down anyway. In that case, 15v may work as well. This would be a less general solution though since it would still depend on having 15v, which not everything supports.

Comment: There is no documentation on the internals i think (its this https://www.vive.com/us/support/cosmos/category_howto/about-the-link-box.html) so its hard to tell if 15v is safe.
So what regulator specifically i could use for this? (electrical engineering is not my field of expertise so i am not familiar with parts available)

Comment: There thousands of questions about voltage regulators on this site, but In that case you should probably buy a 12v power supply unless you're interested in a learning a lot more.